# Macbook Pro 2015 Retina - 15-inch Screws not coming out

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

I was able to use a 1.2mm screwdriver to remove all the screws from the lower case of my Macbook. My intent to is to apply thermal paste, as the Macbook is easily over-heating even when just playing a short YouTube video. I used the same 1.2mm screwdriver to remove a lot of the other screws that are inside the Macbook, but there are just three screws close to the CPU (or I think it's the GPU) unit that are simply just not coming out with my screwdriver.

I've tried multiple rounds of twirling the screwdriver from different angles and even trying to manually pull out the screw, but to no avail.

Any input on how to get rid of these three rascal screws would be greatly appreciated, as I also have a 1/3 broken LCD screen, and even plugging in a monitor screen through HDMI creates substantial overheating.

Thanks.

Comment: Use the correct screwdriver bits? https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Retina+Display+Mid+2015+Logic+Board+Replacement/56210

Comment: @Redarm thank you so much for reminding me about this guide! It turns out that 2.2mm is the one to use for some of those screws that are inside the Macbook. Yikes; what a wake-up call before what could have been an impending disaster! Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have few options left from your description.

Now you need to drill out the heads using preferably a pillar drill so that you don’t cause any more damage.

Then, with a bit of luck you can remove the part and then take out the remains of the screws without damaging the threads.

If not, then it was an expensive learning experience. Oh hope your backup is current.

Comment: Excellent points. Thanks Solar Mike.

Answer (score 0):

[iFixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide) has excellent guides with descriptions of the screws found and the tools used.
It's worth a visit, before attempting to extract the logic board:
[MacBook Pro mid 2015 15-inch Guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Retina+Display+Mid+2015+Logic+Board+Replacement/56210)

Comment: Thanks for sending this guide. It seems that it's the T5 and not the pentalobe P5 screwdrivers that are used when taking out the logic board. I got to the step that talks about the screws on the heat sink brackets, which is most relevant to my OP. I've tried my T5 screwdriver and remember that I got TWO of those screws out from the heat sink bracket, but the other two are stubbornly not getting out.

Comment: Sometimes those screws are slightly stuck at the first turn and a screwdriver with a lever helps to loosen them.  If the head has been damaged, there are bits to get those out (in that case see Solar Mike's answer).